# Restful resources and relational databases are incompatible

Tags: api, rest, design-patterns, api-design

Say I have a relational database with 100+ tables. Each table models some sort of entity (person, address, vehicle, dog, etc etc). Say I also have a restful API and a bunch of people who want to POST data into this database. Many times this data comes in as an XML package or POST data from a web form or something of that nature. **Sometimes we need to post to all the tables of the database, sometimes most, sometimes some, sometimes one.**

Now requiring our clients to post clumps of multi resource data into a 100+ table persistence via the restful way of

```
POST /person
POST /email
POST /vehicle
POST /insurance
```

is insane! So we could have a resource instead that is

```
POST /auto-record
{ post body of key values for all the tables needed to make an 'auto-record' }
```

and it would be connected to some sort of business logic that knows to make inserts into the many tables of the database needed. Okay great. But now that I'm thinking about it, does this design abide by the open/closed principle? If we ever needed to update/add/remove to what an 'auto-record' is then we screw up our clients.

How can restful api's deal with resource groupings? Or does it simply not? Are there alternatives?

Comment: You're running into opinion-based territory with this question. Who said, all programs have to follow all SOLID principals? Oftentimes in the name of other gains you relinquish some principals you would follow normally

Comment: I am not aware of any RESTful pattern violation in your approach. Maybe you should think of renaming your resource name, as `auto-record` is too abstract. Providing a resource which GETs, POSTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs more complex entity (Man with list of his pets, addresses, etc.) should be no problem. See my answer below. P.S.: REST principles are not a doctrine, it is a proper usage of HTTP protocol to work with resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement more versions of your RESTful API resource `/auto-record`. For now modify your resource URI to `/v1/auto-record`. When there will be a feature change request, you will simply provide your customers with a new resource `/v2/auto-record`. Old functionality will be preserved at `/v1/auto-record` and new users will have their needed functionality at `v2/auto-record`.